# how to create server exe for OpenERP version 6.1?

Tags: nsis, odoo

I want to create server exe for OpenERP version 6.1 for Windows. I already created it but the problem is it doesn't have functionality like OpenERP version 6.0 exe server.  For e.g. Start Service, Stop Service, View log, Uninistall. How to add all these functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it myself, but the process is documented in the [OpenERP developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/13_build_and_deploy.html#binary-distribution). It looks like the step you're interested in is this:

```
makensis setup.nsi
```

If you look in the [`setup.nsi` file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/6.1/view/4262/setup.nsi#L162), you can see that it's doing something with the services.

```
Section -StopService
    nsExec::Exec "net stop openerp-server-6.1"
    sleep 2
SectionEnd
```